# How do I find {min,max} repeats with regular expression patterns in Visual Studio or SSMS "Find and Replace"?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, ssms

I knew that we have something like this in the regular expression syntax world.

*The syntax is {min,max}, where `min` is a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and `max` is an integer equal to or greater than `min` indicating the maximum number of matches.

So `{0,}` is the same as `*`, and `{1,}` is the same as `+*`.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

---

But how can I use it in SQL Server Management Studio or Visual Studio's "Find and Replace" window. I only find related Microsoft syntax in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.REGULAREXPRESSIONBUILDER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22%29&rd=true). Like:

> [0-9]^4 matches any 4-digit sequence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Visual Studio regex implementation (in versions up until Visual Studio 2010) is a fairly nonstandard one to say the least, and it doesn't have this feature. You can only spell it out:

`*` or `@`: Match zero or more of the preceding expression

`+` or `#`: Match one or more of the preceding expression

`^n`: Match exactly *n* repetitions of the preceding expression

So for `A{2,4}` you'd have to use `A^4|A^3|A^2` (see polygenelubricant's comment for an explanation why you need to do it in descending order).

More recent versions of Visual Studio support the entire set of .NET regexes.

Comment: `A^2|A^3|A^4` is reluctant, `A^4|A^3|A^2` for greedy version.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Interesting, thanks for the info. I'm not at home right now and couldn't check this yet. What I was wondering: The documentation doesn't mention a "zero or one" quantifier (`?`) - doesn't it exist?

Comment: (+1): I know nothing about Visual Studio regex implementation, but (assuming this is where you're going), `A{2,4}` is equivalent to `AAA?A?`. There may be issues with catastrophic backtracking, though. If at all possible, the `?` should be atomic/possessive. As for the greediness, it's because `{2,4}` will first try to take 4 if possible, then if not 3, then if not 2, in that order. Hence `A^4|A^3|A^2`. If it was `{2,4}?` then it's equivalent to `A^2|A^3|A^4`. The difference shows when there are exactly 3 A. The greedy will match all 3, the reluctant will match only 2 leaving 1 unmatched.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It might be worth adding that VS2012 has this feature. :)

Comment: As of VS2012 the regex syntax has changed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx