# RegEx for VS 2010 to find #XXXXXX where X is HEX number

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

What regex should I use for VS 2010 to find any "#12345A" string - 6 symbols (HEX color) with "" on both sides?

I've tried [^0-9]#[0-9]{6}[^0-9] to find at least 6 symbols, but if failed...

I am trying to find all custom colors in projects (non-custom colors have 8 symbols with # before).

Comment: Hex colors may also contain letters from A to F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly, you need to include the hex letters, and secondly why not use `"` instead of `not a digit`. Also, VS's quantifiers are a bit different than usual, so you need to escape `#` (because otherwise it's equivalent to the `+` quantifier) and repetition works like `^6`:

```
"\#[0-9a-fA-F]^6"
```

[See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350929/1633117)

Comment: I'd escape some chars here: `\"\#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\"` ... Oh, hey @m.buettner, we meet again ;)

Comment: @Ariaan wow this time it's actually necessary. VS's regex engine is truly a bit odd.

Comment: Well, one of the reasons I stay by my rule `When in doubt, escape it!`